# How do I make Ubuntu full scale in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

I have the guest additions installed. I've increased the resolution to (1600x1200 max). My monitor is a 25" (widescreen) and supports up to 1920x1280. How do I get the window to resize to fill the entire screen. It seems like Ubuntu only supports 4:3 ratio and not 16:9. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you have tried Full Screen and Seemless modes.  My guess is you might not have to increase the Video Memory you have configured for Virtual Box.

For size estimates: with 64 Mb of Video memory configured in Virtual Box, I am running a Full Screen Mode display of Ubuntu 10.04 at 2560x1024 resolution.

Comment: Seamless mode is greyed out for me. How do I enable it?